# Is a trigger function supposed to trigger another trigger?

Tags: postgresql

I have a trigger_function_a that is triggered before insert or update of field_1 or field_2. I have another trigger_function_b that is triggered before insert or update of field_3 or field_4:

before insert or update of field_1 or field_2 => trigger_function_a

before insert or update of field_3 or field_4 => trigger_function_b

Now, trigger_function_a modifies field_3. Is trigger_function_b supposed to be triggered? I have tried it, but it is not triggered. Why? I have searched all available docs, but I have not found an answer to this.

Please don't care for syntax here. The trigger functions do work for themselves if I modify the fields by myself, e. g. via SQL. All I'm asking here is: Is a trigger function supposed to be fired if another trigger function modifies its fields?

Comment: This may be of interest: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103402/how-to-prevent-a-postgresql-trigger-from-being-fired-by-another-trigger

Comment: @verhie: Thank you. Will have a look into that. BTW, this is postgresql 9.5

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, `trigger_function_b`will not be called in this case.

Look at [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html#SQL-CREATETRIGGER-NOTES):

> A column-specific trigger (one defined using the `UPDATE OF column_name` syntax) will fire when any of its columns are listed as targets in the `UPDATE` command's `SET` list. It is possible for a column's value to change even when the trigger is not fired, because changes made to the row's contents by `BEFORE UPDATE` triggers are not considered. Conversely, a command such as `UPDATE ... SET x = x ...` will fire a trigger on column `x`, even though the column's value did not change.

The key point here is that a trigger fires if and only if the column appears in the `SET` list.

Comment: So, nevertheless, this *is* a matter of the syntax. I used NEW.field_3 = ... syntax. Seems I have to UPDATE things...

Comment: It says "*listed as targets in the `UPDATE` command's `SET` list*". If you assign to `NEW.field_3` in a function, that is something different.